# Work email field is missing on SharePoint Online user profile

Tags: sharepoint-online, email

I just bought a SharePoint Online plan 1, just for learning (I need to learn it ASAP). I have serveral site collection and only one user: `MyName@MyOnlineCompany.onmicrosoft.co`m.

I wanted to receive sharepoints alerts on `MyName@MyCompany.com`, so I went to my profile and tried to change work email field, however no work email field is on my profile.

So the question is, how can I receive alerts to `MyName@MyCompany.com`?

Also, how can I read email sent to `MyName@MyOnlineCompany.onmicrosoft.com` (I sent test emails to this email address and it seems to work).

Comment: How did you try to change your user profile? Try going to `https://<yourtenant>-admin.sharepoint.com/`, clicking on user profiles, and then changing your profile that way.

Comment: As for your last question, Open the Mail link from the top suite bar. It shows your mail in outlook.

Comment: @wjervis I also tried that way, no work email field

Comment: @uberz91, that would send an email to MyName@MyOnlineCompany.onmicrosoft.com. This is not the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I try to edit my work email by going to my profile and clicking edit profile, I cannot change it either:
[image]

However, you can go to the admin site (`https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com/`), click on User Profiles > Manage User Profiles, search and edit your profile.  Scroll down to find Work email, and you will be able to edit it:
[image]

To view your email, open the app launcher (or [waffle](https://blogs.office.com/2015/06/25/office-365-users-gain-one-click-access-to-third-party-apps/), as some are calling it), then click on Mail:
[image]

Comment: Mail app is not on my app launcher. I have News, OneDrive, My Site, Word Online, Excel Online, Power Point Online, One Note Online, Office 365 Store and Admin. Additionally, I cannot find Mail app in Office 365 Store

Comment: How curious.  Do you have Exchange settings in the admin center? What version/level of O365 do you have?

Comment: I have purchased SharePoint Online plan 1, not Office 365, https://products.office.com/en-us/SharePoint/compare-sharepoint-plans. I think it doesn't include mail. I tried https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?realm=MyOnlineCompany.onmicrosoft.com#path=/mail but it shows a blank page. I think I need Office 365 to have email

Comment: Ah, yeah.  SPO plans do not include Exchange Online.  Setting your work email should send any SharePoint generated emails to it.

Comment: Thank You man!)

Answer (score 1):

To setup work email go to: Office 365 admin center -> Admin SharePoint -> user profiles. And there select manage user profiles. You should find your user there and then you can edit properties of the user. 
To check email @MyOnlineCompany.onmicrosoft.com just press Mail icon in App launcher - button on left, in the ribbon

Comment: Mail app is not on my app launcher. I have News, OneDrive, My Site, Word Online, Excel Online, Power Point Online, One Note Online, Office 365 Store and Admin. Additionally, I cannot find Mail app in Office 365 Store –